# Android Expandable List View Update

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-notifications

I am implementing a chatting application, where I have made a service to listen all the presence changed. On the change of the presence I want to update the data and I am unable to update the data that is showing in the expandable list view. Please suggest me a means to do the same.

```
    public class UserMenuActivity extends ExpandableListActivity {

        private XMPPConnection connection;
        String name,availability,subscriptionStatus;
        TextView tv_Status;

        /** Variable Define here */
        private String[] data = { "View my profile", "New Multiperson Chat",
                "New Broad Cast Message", "New Contact Category", "New Group",
                "Invite to CCM", "Search", "Expand All", "Settings", "Help",
        "Close" };
        private String[] data_Contact = { "Rename Category","Move Contact to Category", "View my profile",
                "New Multiperson Chat", "New Broad Cast Message",
                "New Contact Category", "New Group", "Invite to CCM", "Search",
                "Expand All", "Settings", "Help", "Close" };
        private String[] data_child_contact = { "Open chat", "Delete Contact","View my profile",
                "New Multiperson Chat", "New Broad Cast Message",
                "New Contact Category", "New Group", "Invite to CCM", "Search",
                "Expand All", "Settings", "Help", "Close" };
        private String[] menuItem = { "Chats", "Contacts", "CGM Groups", "Pending","Request" };
        private List<String> menuItemList = Arrays.asList(menuItem);

        private int commonGroupPosition = 0;
        private String etAlertVal;
        private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
        private int categoryID, listPos;
        /** New Code here.. */
        private ArrayList<String> groupNames;
        private ArrayList<ArrayList<ChildItems>> childs;
        private UserMenuAdapter adapter;
        private Object object;

        private String[] data2 = { "PIN Michelle", "IP Call" };
        private ListView mlist2;
        private ImageButton mimBtnMenu;
        private LinearLayout mllpopmenu;
        private View popupView;
        private PopupWindow popupWindow;
        private AlertDialog.Builder alert;
        private EditText input;
        private TextView mtvUserName, mtvUserTagLine;
        private ExpandableListView mExpandableListView;
        public static List<CategoryDataClass> categoryList;
        private boolean menuType = false;
        private String childValContact="";
        public static Context context;

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            if (mllpopmenu.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                mllpopmenu.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                if (CCMStaticVariable.CommonConnection.isConnected()) {
                    CCMStaticVariable.CommonConnection.disconnect();
                }
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
                if (mllpopmenu.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    mllpopmenu.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                } else {
                    if (commonGroupPosition >= 4 && menuType == true) {
                        if(childValContact == ""){
                            mllpopmenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            mlist2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(UserMenuActivity.this,
                                    R.layout.listviewtext, R.id.tvMenuText,
                                    data_Contact));

                        }else{
                            mllpopmenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            mlist2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(UserMenuActivity.this,
                                    R.layout.listviewtext, R.id.tvMenuText,
                                    data_child_contact));

                        }

                    } else if (commonGroupPosition == 0) {
                        mllpopmenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mlist2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(UserMenuActivity.this,
                                R.layout.listviewtext, R.id.tvMenuText, data));
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
            super.onCreate(icicle);
            setContentView(R.layout.usermenulayout);
            dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(UserMenuActivity.this);

            //this.context = context.getApplicationContext();

            XMPPConn.getContactList();

            connection = CCMStaticVariable.CommonConnection;


            Presence userPresence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
            userPresence.setPriority(24);
            userPresence.setMode(Presence.Mode.away);
            connection.sendPacket(userPresence);        


        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();       
            Presence userPresence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
            userPresence.setPriority(24);
            userPresence.setMode(Presence.Mode.away);
            connection.sendPacket(userPresence);
            XMPPConn.getContactList();
            setExpandableListView();
        }

        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

            if (groupPosition == 1 && childPosition == 0) {
                startActivity(new Intent(UserMenuActivity.this,
                        InvitetoCCMActivity.class));
            } else if (groupPosition == 1 && childPosition != 0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(UserMenuActivity.this,
                        UserChatActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("userNameVal",
                        XMPPConn.mfriendList.get(childPosition - 1).friendName);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else if (groupPosition == 2 && childPosition == 0) {
                startActivity(new Intent(UserMenuActivity.this,
                        CreateGroupActivity.class));
            } else if (groupPosition == 2 && childPosition != 0) {
                String GROUP_NAME = childs.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition)
                .getName().toString();
                int end = GROUP_NAME.indexOf("(");
                CCMStaticVariable.groupName = GROUP_NAME.substring(0, end).trim();
                startActivity(new Intent(UserMenuActivity.this,
                        GroupsActivity.class));
            } else if (groupPosition >= 4) {
                childValContact = childs.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition).getName().trim();
                showToast("user==>"+childValContact, 0);
            }
            return false;
        }

        private void setExpandableListView() {
            /***###############GROUP ARRAY ############################*/
            final ArrayList<String> groupNames = new ArrayList<String>();
            groupNames.add("Chats (2)");
            groupNames.add("Contacts (" + XMPPConn.mfriendList.size() + ")");
            groupNames.add("CGM Groups (" + XMPPConn.mGroupList.size() + ")");
            groupNames.add("Pending (1)");

            XMPPConn.getGroup();
            categoryList = dbHelper.getAllCategory();
            /**Group From Sever*/
            if (XMPPConn.mGroupList.size() > 0) {
                for (int g = 0; g < XMPPConn.mGroupList.size(); g++) {
                    XMPPConn.getGroupContact(XMPPConn.mGroupList.get(g).groupName);
                    groupNames.add(XMPPConn.mGroupList.get(g).groupName + "("
                            + XMPPConn.mGroupContactList.size()+ ")");
                }
            } 
            if(categoryList.size() > 0){
                for (int cat = 0; cat < categoryList.size(); cat++) {
                    groupNames.add(categoryList.get(cat).getCategoryName()+ "(0)");
                }
            }
            this.groupNames = groupNames;

            /*** ###########CHILD ARRAY * #################*/
            ArrayList<ArrayList<ChildItems>> childs = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ChildItems>>();

            ArrayList<ChildItems> child = new ArrayList<ChildItems>();
            child.add(new ChildItems("Alisha", "Hi",0));
            child.add(new ChildItems("Michelle", "Good Morning",0));

            childs.add(child);

            child = new ArrayList<ChildItems>();
            child.add(new ChildItems("", "",0));
            if (XMPPConn.mfriendList.size() > 0) {
                for (int n = 0; n < XMPPConn.mfriendList.size(); n++) {
                    child.add(new ChildItems(XMPPConn.mfriendList.get(n).friendNickName,
                            XMPPConn.mfriendList.get(n).friendStatus, 
                            XMPPConn.mfriendList.get(n).friendState));
                }
            }
            childs.add(child);
            /************** CGM Group Child here *********************/
            child = new ArrayList<ChildItems>();
            child.add(new ChildItems("", "",0));

            if (XMPPConn.mGroupList.size() > 0) {
                for (int grop = 0; grop < XMPPConn.mGroupList.size(); grop++) {
                    child.add(new ChildItems(
                            XMPPConn.mGroupList.get(grop).groupName + " ("
                            + XMPPConn.mGroupList.get(grop).groupUserCount
                            + ")", "",0));
                }
            }
            childs.add(child);

            child = new ArrayList<ChildItems>();
            child.add(new ChildItems("Shuchi",
                    "Pending (Waiting for Authorization)",0));
            childs.add(child);
            /************************ Group Contact List *************************/
            if (XMPPConn.mGroupList.size() > 0) {
                for (int g = 0; g < XMPPConn.mGroupList.size(); g++) {
                    /** Contact List */
                    XMPPConn.getGroupContact(XMPPConn.mGroupList.get(g).groupName);
                    child = new ArrayList<ChildItems>();
                    for (int con = 0; con < XMPPConn.mGroupContactList.size(); con++) {
                        child.add(new ChildItems(
                                XMPPConn.mGroupContactList.get(con).friendName,
                                XMPPConn.mGroupContactList.get(con).friendStatus,0));
                    }
                    childs.add(child);
                }
            } 
            if(categoryList.size() > 0){
                for (int cat = 0; cat < categoryList.size(); cat++) {
                    child = new ArrayList<ChildItems>();
                    child.add(new ChildItems("-none-", "",0));
                    childs.add(child);
                }
            }
            this.childs = childs;

            /** Set Adapter here */
            adapter = new UserMenuAdapter(this, groupNames, childs);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
            object = this;

            mlist2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list2);
            mimBtnMenu = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imBtnMenu);
            mllpopmenu = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llpopmenu);
            mtvUserName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvUserName);
            mtvUserTagLine = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvUserTagLine);

            //Set User name..
            System.out.println("CCMStaticVariable.loginUserName==="
                    + CCMStaticVariable.loginUserName);
            if (!CCMStaticVariable.loginUserName.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                mtvUserName.setText("" + CCMStaticVariable.loginUserName);
            }
            /** Expandable List set here.. */
            mExpandableListView = (ExpandableListView) this
            .findViewById(android.R.id.list);
            mExpandableListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                        int groupPosition, long id) {

                    XMPPConn.getContactList();

                    if (parent.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition)) {
                        commonGroupPosition = 0;
                    }else{
                        commonGroupPosition = groupPosition;
                    }
                    String GROUP_NAME = groupNames.get(groupPosition);
                    int end = groupNames.get(groupPosition).indexOf("(");
                    String GROUP_NAME_VALUE = GROUP_NAME.substring(0, end).trim();
                    if (menuItemList.contains(GROUP_NAME_VALUE)) {
                        menuType = false;
                        CCMStaticVariable.groupCatName = GROUP_NAME_VALUE;
                    } else {
                        menuType = true;
                        CCMStaticVariable.groupCatName = GROUP_NAME_VALUE;
                    }
                    long findCatId = dbHelper.getCategoryID(GROUP_NAME_VALUE);
                    if (findCatId != 0) {
                        categoryID = (int) findCatId;
                    }
                    childValContact="";
                    showToast("Clicked on==" + GROUP_NAME_VALUE, 0);
                    return false;
                }
            });

            /** Click on item */
            mlist2.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos,long arg3) {
                    if (commonGroupPosition >= 4) {
                        if(childValContact == ""){
                            if (pos == 0) {
                                showAlertEdit(CCMStaticVariable.groupCatName);
                            }                   
                            /** Move contact to catgory */
                            if (pos == 1) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(UserMenuActivity.this,AddContactCategoryActivity.class));
                            }
                        }else{
                            if(pos == 0){
                                Intent intent = new Intent(UserMenuActivity.this,UserChatActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("userNameVal",childValContact);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                            if(pos == 1){
                                XMPPConn.removeEntry(childValContact);
                                showToast("Contact deleted sucessfully", 0);
                                Intent intent = new Intent(UserMenuActivity.this,UserMenuActivity.class);
                            }
                        }

                    } else {
                        /** MyProfile */
                        if (pos == 0) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(UserMenuActivity.this,
                                    MyProfileActivity.class));
                        }
                        /** New multiperson chat start */
                        if (pos == 1) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(UserMenuActivity.this,
                                    NewMultipersonChatActivity.class));
                        }
                        /** New Broadcast message */
                        if (pos == 2) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(UserMenuActivity.this,
                                    NewBroadcastMessageActivity.class));
                        }
                        /** Click on add category */
                        if (pos == 3) {
                            showAlertAdd();
                        }
                        if (pos == 4) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(UserMenuActivity.this,
                                    CreateGroupActivity.class));
                        }

                        if (pos == 5) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(UserMenuActivity.this,
                                    InvitetoCCMActivity.class));
                        }
                        if (pos == 6) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(UserMenuActivity.this,
                                    SearchActivity.class));
                        }
                        if (pos == 7) {
                            onGroupExpand(2);
                            for (int i = 0; i < groupNames.size(); i++) {
                                mExpandableListView.expandGroup(i);
                            }
                        }
                        /** Click on settings */
                        if (pos == 8) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(UserMenuActivity.this,
                                    SettingsActivity.class));
                        }
                        if (pos == 10) {
                            System.exit(0);
                        }

                        if (pos == 14) {
                            if (mllpopmenu.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                                mllpopmenu.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                if (popupWindow.isShowing()) {
                                    popupWindow.dismiss();
                                }
                            } else {
                                mllpopmenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                mlist2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(
                                        UserMenuActivity.this,
                                        R.layout.listviewtext, R.id.tvMenuText,
                                        data));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        /** Toast message display here.. */
        private void showToast(String msg, int time) {
            Toast.makeText(this, msg, time).show();
        }

BroadcastReceiver UpdateList = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(UserMenuActivity.this, "CALLED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }
    };

        public String showSubscriptionStatus(String friend){
            return friend;


        }

    }
```

Service.class

```
    public class UpdaterService extends Service {
        private XMPPConnection connection;
        String Friend;
        String user = "";

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            // Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            super.onCreate();
        }   

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDestroy();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            showToast("My Service Started", 0);
            connection = getConnection();
            if (connection.isConnected()) {
                final Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
                RosterListener r1 = new RosterListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void presenceChanged(Presence presence) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        XMPPConn.getContactList();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void entriesUpdated(Collection<String> arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        //notification("entriesUpdated");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void entriesDeleted(Collection<String> arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        //notification("entriesDeleted");
                    }


                    @Override
                    public void entriesAdded(Collection<String> arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Iterator<String> it = arg0.iterator();
                        if (it.hasNext()) {
                            user = it.next();
                        }
                        RosterEntry entry = roster.getEntry(user);
                        if(entry.getType().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("to")){
                            int index_of_Alpha = Friend.indexOf("@");
                            String subID = Friend.substring(0, index_of_Alpha);

                            notification("Hi "+subID+" wants to add you");
                        }               
                    }
                };

                if (roster != null) {
                    roster.setSubscriptionMode(Roster.SubscriptionMode.manual);
                    System.out.println("subscription going on");
                    roster.addRosterListener(r1);
                }

            } else {
                showToast("Connection lost-", 0);
            }
        }

        protected void showToast(String msg, int time) {
            Toast.makeText(this, msg, time).show();
        }

        private XMPPConnection getConnection() {
            return CCMStaticVariable.CommonConnection;
        }

        /** Notification manager */
        private void notification(CharSequence message) {

            String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
            int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
            CharSequence tickerText = message;
            long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
            Context context = getApplicationContext();



            CharSequence contentTitle = "CCM";
            CharSequence contentText = message;
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ManageNotification.class);
            notificationIntent.putExtra("Subscriber_ID",user );

            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                    notificationIntent, 0);
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText,
                    contentIntent);
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            final int HELLO_ID = 1;
            mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);

        }

}
```

Here is my adapter class

```
public class UserMenuAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private ArrayList<String> groups;
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<ChildItems>> childs;
    private Context context;
    public LayoutInflater inflater;

    ImageView img_availabiliy;

    private static final int[] EMPTY_STATE_SET = {};
    private static final int[] GROUP_EXPANDED_STATE_SET =
            {android.R.attr.state_expanded};
    private static final int[][] GROUP_STATE_SETS = {
         EMPTY_STATE_SET, // 0
         GROUP_EXPANDED_STATE_SET // 1
    };

    public UserMenuAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> groups,
            ArrayList<ArrayList<ChildItems>> childs) {
        this.context = context;
        this.groups = groups;
        this.childs = childs;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childs.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return (long) (groupPosition * 1024 + childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = null;
        if (convertView != null)
            v = convertView;
        else
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_layout, parent, false);
        ChildItems ci = (ChildItems) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvChild);
        tv.setText(ci.getName());
        TextView tv2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvChild2);
        tv2.setText(ci.getDailyStatus());
        img_availabiliy = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.img_childlayout_AVAILABILITY);
        ImageView friendPics = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.ivFriendPics);


        if(ci.getStatusState() == 1){
            img_availabiliy.setImageResource(R.drawable.online);
        }
        else if(ci.getStatusState()==0){
            img_availabiliy.setImageResource(R.drawable.offline);           
        }           
        else if (ci.getStatusState()==2) {
            img_availabiliy.setImageResource(R.drawable.away);
        }       
        else if(ci.getStatusState()==3){
            img_availabiliy.setImageResource(R.drawable.busy);
        }
        else{
            img_availabiliy.setImageDrawable(null);
        }       
        if((groupPosition == 1 && childPosition == 0)){
            friendPics.setImageResource(R.drawable.inviteto_ccm);
            img_availabiliy.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else if(groupPosition == 2 && childPosition == 0){
            friendPics.setImageResource(R.drawable.new_ccmgroup);
            img_availabiliy.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);            
        }else{
            if(ci.getPicture()!= null){
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(ci.getPicture(), 0, ci.getPicture().length);
                bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 50, 50, true);
                friendPics.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }else{
                friendPics.setImageResource(R.drawable.avatar);
            }

            img_availabiliy.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return childs.get(groupPosition).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groups.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return groups.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return (long) (groupPosition * 1024); 
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = null;
        if (convertView != null)
            v = convertView;
        else
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_layout, parent, false);
        String gt = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        TextView tv2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvGroup);
        if (gt != null)
            tv2.setText(gt);
        /**Set Image on group layout, Max/min*/
        View ind = v.findViewById( R.id.explist_indicator);
        View groupInd = v.findViewById( R.id.llgroup);
        if( ind != null ) {
            ImageView indicator = (ImageView)ind;           
            if( getChildrenCount( groupPosition ) == 0 ) {
                indicator.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );
            } else {
                indicator.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                int stateSetIndex = ( isExpanded ? 1 : 0) ;
                Drawable drawable = indicator.getDrawable();
                drawable.setState(GROUP_STATE_SETS[stateSetIndex]);
            }
        }
        if( groupInd != null ) {
            RelativeLayout indicator2 = (RelativeLayout)groupInd;
            if( getChildrenCount( groupPosition ) == 0 ) {
                indicator2.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );             
            } else {
                indicator2.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                int stateSetIndex = ( isExpanded ? 1 : 0) ;
                Drawable drawable2 = indicator2.getBackground();                
                drawable2.setState(GROUP_STATE_SETS[stateSetIndex]);
            }
        }
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
    }

    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
    }

}
```

I just want to update my list in ON PRESENCE CHANGED method in the Service class.. Please suggest me a means to do the same.

Comment: Could you possibly try to simplify the code and be more specific? That way there is a bigger chance that somebody can/will help you. I searched for notifydatasetchanged in your code and could not find it?

Comment: @TommyTh Please have a look bro. I have edited the code and added notifydatasetchanged in the USERMENU activity ( in the last ) It is called (i have cheked it) but the list is not updated. Please have a look and help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

> listView.notifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is,

You can use [BroadCastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html), Interface or [ResultReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ResultReceiver.html)

For ResultReceiver you can check a demo from my github [`here`](https://github.com/lalit3686/ResultReceiverDemo).

Create a `BroadCastReceiver` and register it in your `Activity`. Then from `presenceChanged()` method in your `Service` you can fire that `BroadCastReceiver` and update your `ExpandableListView` in your Activity where you have implemented the `BroadCastReceiver` using `expandlistView.notifyDataSetChanged()`

In Activity,

```
public static final String ACTION_UPDATE = "ACTION_UPDATE";

BroadcastReceiver UpdateListsReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ......
        registerReceiver(finishActivitiesReceiver, 
                                            new IntentFilter(ACTION_UPDATE));
    }
```

In your Service,

```
     @Override
     public void presenceChanged(Presence presence) {
           XMPPConn.getContactList();
           sendBroadcast(new Intent(Activity_Name.ACTION_UPDATE));
     }
```

Also, don't forget to unregister your BroadCastReciever in `onDestroy()` or `onPause()` using

```
unregisterReceiver(UpdateListsReceiver);
```

Comment: I have done exactly same as per your suggestion. but not working :(